# ImportError: No named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package

Tags: python3

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux in general.

I created a dual boot OS on my laptop (Windows 10 and Ubuntu).

- Typing: `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` (or even `python-tk`) didn't work.
- Trying to install the `python3-dev` or `python-devel` (no luck).
- Downloading Tcl and Tk to manually install.

In Windows 10 Bash Subsystem the Tk and Tcl are already included, so I thought Ubuntu already had it.  But, I want to use my Ubuntu desktop to develop Python GUI apps.

So, how can I install the Tcl/Tk to be use in Python 3.5 for GUI development?

I loaded Python 3.5.2 fine but need the GUI modules enabled.

The code to test that Tk is working is:

1. Type `python3`
2. Type:

   ```
   import tkinter   
   tkinter._test()
   ```
3. Result: a GUI pop-up displaying `This is a Tcl/Tk version..`

Comment: *" I loaded Python 3.5.2"* - how exactly? if you are running a manually installed python then installing system python packages with apt-get is unlikely to help

Comment: I saw that your answer to your own question is to compile Tcl/Tk from source but I don't think that is needed unless you manually installed Python, i.e., without using the Apt package manager. Can you clarify if you had installed Python manually? Installing `python3-tk` and then running the Python code you provided works on my system Python 3.

Answer (score 44):

`sudo apt-get install python3-tk` Installs `tkinter` for Python3.x.x

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084416/tkinter-module-not-found-on-ubuntu
https://pythonprogramming.net/python-3-tkinter-basics-tutorial/

Comment: Note -- for python3.6 in which python3.5 was my default, I had to use ...install python3.6-tk....

Comment: +1.  I would add for those reading this that tkinter does not seem to have a PyPI package so that using the Ubuntu package manager as suggested in this answer is the likely the next best option.

Comment: @dpritch There is a package available in the Universe  repository called[ pypibrowser](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=pypibrowser&searchon=names which supplies the functionality I believe you are looking for. Cheers!

Comment: `python3-tkinter` for me on Fedora with `dnf` at least.

Comment: @Pysis I'm sorry for any confusion you may have experienced. This answer like this entire site is about Ubuntu. You might benefit from [the tour.](https://askubuntu.com/tour) The first sentence makes it pretty clear, if not, further clarity is available [here.](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) Cheers!

Answer (score 34):

For a python 3.6 virtual environment with Python 3.5 as the "system" python (Ubuntu)  , I had to install tk 3.6 to match;

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6-tk
```

My default python in ubuntu was 3.5, so when using a venv for 3.6, I would get an import error. Drove me crazy for a while.

[Edit: As this question ages]

In general, it seems if one is using a virtual environment with a python of a different version than that of ones base machine, one must install tk for the version of python used in the virtual environment.

```
sudo apt install python3.x-tk
```

Where 3.x would match the version of the virtual environment.

[Edit]

It may be necessary to add the repository for tk. In my experience, it was the same repository from which I pulled python3.6, but that may change with time;

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

Comment: Interesting. You might go so far as to explain which PPA you installed it from as as far as I can see [python3.6-tk doesn't exist in the repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=python3.6-tk&searchon=names) at this moment.

Comment: I made a further edit in an attempt to make it more current.

Comment: FINALLY!  This is the worked for me when `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` did not.  Thanks

Comment: For python 3.7 I had to use `sudo apt-get install python3.7-tk` to make it work

Comment: That was it. The only solution that worked for me in twelve pages of Stackoverflow.

Comment: For python 3.10 I had to use sudo apt-get install python3.10-tk, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting the same error as **"ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'"** for python3.5 in-spite of doing the following things:
 - Installing python3-tk and tkinter-dev
 - Tkinter directory being available in /usr/lib/python3.5.

The observed error was from the following file:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tkinter/**init**.py", line 35, in 
>       import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk

However, when I simply ran the python from /usr/bin like ***/usr/bin/python3.5*** from terminal, it worked for me!

**In short, just ensure the python version being run from terminal has the tkinter installed and configured** :)

I have Ubuntu16.04 installed on my system which comes with default python2.7 and python3.5

Answer (score 0):

This might be interesting when installing from source (which most python users won't):

After installing [tcl and tk](http://www.tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html).

Go back to your version of Python, do `make`. And, if multiple version of `python` exist, do a `make altinstall`.

1. Open Python3.5
2. type:

   ```
   import tkinter
   tkinter._test()
   ```
3. results OK - pop GUI opened and working as expected.

Comment: -1 This will not be relevant to most people as most will install via package manager rather than from source.

Comment: added introduction, so it won't confuse and still might help someone

Comment: want or won't ?

Answer (score 0):

Installing just library files may not work since you want to use library itself not develop it.

This worked for me:

```
$ sudo apt install tk8.6-dev
```

Comment: while this may answer the question, perhaps you could expand it to explain what the above command does and why it could fix the issue?

Comment: **ismailarilik** What **@JoshuaBesneatte** is trying to say is: don't only give the requester the commands, but explain what the commands do and why he/she should apply it. *As it stands, your answer is likely to be deleted because of lack of quality...*  **:-(**