# ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package

Tags: 16.04, python, python3, tkinter

After an `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get the following error:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-tk package')
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package
```

I have `python3-tk` installed. I already tried purging and installing it. Doesn't change anything. (Interestingly, the `/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter` still existed after pruging... and manually removing it did only lead to another error)

How can I fix this problem?

### Did not solve the problem:

```
$ sudo apt-get install tk8.6-dev
$ sudo apt-get install python3-tkinter # does not exist
$ sudo apt-get install python3-tk  # exists and is installed
```

### Comment answers

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter
total 372
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1791 Nov 28 17:50 colorchooser.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1412 Nov 28 17:50 commondialog.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1493 Nov 28 17:50 constants.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1568 Nov 28 17:50 dialog.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11488 Nov 28 17:50 dnd.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14502 Nov 28 17:50 filedialog.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6581 Nov 28 17:50 font.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 162249 Nov 28 17:50 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    148 Nov 28 17:50 __main__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3701 Nov 28 17:50 messagebox.py
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Nov 30 08:12 __pycache__
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1814 Nov 28 17:50 scrolledtext.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11424 Nov 28 17:50 simpledialog.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  77014 Nov 28 17:50 tix.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  55839 Nov 28 17:50 ttk.py
```

When moving the directory,  I get:

```
$ sudo mv tkinter tkinter-backup
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

More info

```
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3

$ apt list python3
Listing... Done
python3/xenial,now 3.5.1-3 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: What do you see if you run `ls -l /usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter`? You say that you manually removed it resulting in another error, what was that error?

Comment: Where is your python installation from? Can you run `which python3` and `apt list python3`?

Comment: @Steve See edited question for the answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No named '\_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815874/importerror-no-named-tkinter-please-install-the-python3-tk-package)

Answer (score 1):

The python3-tk package has support for python versions 3.6 and 3.7, not 3.5, which is your default.  Change your default python to a version supported if your work supports that.  Otherwise, if you really need version3.5, you will need to track down the support files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting the same error as **"ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'"** for python3.5 in-spite of doing the following things:
 - Installing python3-tk and tkinter-dev
 - Tkinter directory being available in /usr/lib/python3.5.

The observed error was from the following file:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tkinter/**init**.py", line 35, in 
>       import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk

However, when I simply ran the python from /usr/bin like ***/usr/bin/python3.5*** from terminal, it worked for me!

**In short, just ensure the python version being run from terminal has the tkinter installed and configured** :)

I have Ubuntu16.04 installed on my system which comes with default python2.7 and python3.5

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `import Tkinter` (with a capital T) in your python program? That did it for me.

Comment: Capital T is for Python 2.7.12. OP is trying to use Python 3.x.