# Install tkinter package for python-3.5 with python-3.4 also present

Tags: package-management, python, python3, tkinter

I have 3 pythons installed on my system (ubuntu 14.04): `2.7`, `3.4`, `3.5`. I want to use `matplotlib` on a virtual environment based on `python-3.5`. But importing it gave following error:

`ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package`

So, I installed it using `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` as said [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815874/importerror-no-named-tkinter-please-install-the-python3-tk-package), but still I am not able to `import matplotlib` and it gives the same error again?

I think the problem is that the `python3-tk` package is installed for `python-3.4` only. What can I do to install it for `python-3.5`?